# Space inserted before and after custom command

Tags: spacing, macros, environments

I created a custom command to be used for printing sizes. For easier checking the commands options I use a custom 'switch' environment.

Sadly there is always a space before and after the inserted sizes and I cannot find a way to get rid of them.

Where's my mistake?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{xifthen}

\newenvironment{switch}[1]{%
    \newboolean{default}
    \setboolean{default}{true}
    %
    \newcommand{\case}{}
    \renewcommand{\case}[2]{\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{##1}}{%
        \setboolean{default}{false}##2}{}}%
    %
    \newcommand{\default}{}
    \renewcommand{\default}[1]{\ifthenelse{\boolean{default}}{##1}{}}
}{}

\newcommand{\sizesDWLmm}[4][]{%
    \begin{switch}{#1}%
        \case{short}{(DWL~#2~$\times$~#3~$\times$~#4mm)} %
        \case{long}{(depth~#2mm~$\times$ width~#3mm~$\times$ length~#4mm)} %
        \default{(#2~$\times$~#3~$\times$~#4mm)} %
    \end{switch}
}


\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas at blandit libero. Curabitur luctus pulvinar \sizesDWLmm{4}{5}{9} mauris ac accumsan. Nulla sollicitudin ex \sizesDWLmm[long]{4}{5}{9} ac pellentesque accumsan. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Donec vel venenatis nunc. In ac vulputate nunc. Aliquam \sizesDWLmm[short]{4}{5}{9} volutpat ultricies consectetur. Nullam quis orci id nisi facilisis dapibus vel ut risus.

\end{document}
```

This is how this MWE looks:

[image]

Comment: You have lots of spurious spaces in your definition (the end of lines). Beside this you shouldn't use \newcommand inside such an environment.

Comment: Line endings, end various of those lines with `%` other wise the line break at the end of the line is converted into a space

Comment: See [What is the use of percent signs (`%`) at the end of lines?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/5764)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Is there a better way than using \newcommand inside \newenvironment? What's your recommendation?